# how to configure multiple yii application over a single ip in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, deployment, yii2

in my case have two yii2 appliation and want to configure in such way that i can access both application like below.

```
app 1 frontend - somedomain.com/app1/
app 1 backend -  somedomain.com/app1/admin

app 2 frontend - somedomain.com/app2/
app 2 backend -  somedomain.com/app2/admin
```

**what i have tried.**

i have created 5 nginx config file `defualt.conf, app1-frontend.conf, app1-backend.conf, app2-frontend.conf, app2-backend.conf`

**defualt.conf**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name somedomain.com;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /app1/admin {
        proxy_pass  https://localhost:3001;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
    }

    location /app2/admin {
        proxy_pass  https://localhost:5001;
    }
}
```

**app1-frontend.conf**

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 3000;
    server_name  127.0.0.1 localhost;

    root /home/dev/Desktop/app1/frontend/web;

    access_log  /home/dev/Desktop/app1/vagrant/nginx/log/frontend-access.log;
    error_log   /home/dev/Desktop/app1/vagrant/nginx/log/frontend-error.log;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

and for other config like `app1-backend.conf, app2-frontend.conf, app2-backend.conf` everything is same except port and the document root.

when i visit `http://somedomain.com/app1/` i got only html page and in other appliation routes got `404` and for `http://somedomain.com/app1/admin` i got `502` error.

does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What you should google is called SSO (single sing on). If you use 3rd party authentication provider (like OAuth) you can achieve the desired behaviour - I got such env. up and running with JWT (JSON wet token) and Auth0.